# What is a shockwave edge?

Tags: waves, vacuum, shock-waves

In the article [Glass Half Empty](https://what-if.xkcd.com/6/) from *What If?*, there is a drawing contain *shockwave edge*:

[image]

What does it mean? There is no explanation in the article about this. It seems like a flow or something. The lower half of the left glass is vacuum, and the upper half is water. The [edge wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_wave) seems to be irrelevant, since it is a surface gravity wave fixed by refraction against a rigid boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just the [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) front also called the ramp.  It is where the density, temperature, pressure, and bulk flow speed change in a semi-[discontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) fashion.  It is discontinuous only in that the changes in the above parameters occur on a scale length comparable to or shorter than the *communication scale* of the media, in this case the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) for [binary particle collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases).